# Show wordpress posts on linkedin company page

Tags: wordpress, blog, rss, feeds, linkedin

I have a customer with a wordpress blog that wants to add their posts to their LinkedIn company page.

Is it possible to add a wordpress feed like you can in user profiles?
I saw that there was a setting called "Company Blog RSS Feed" but that is already taken by another blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add one feed to your LinkedIn company info page.

A workaround is to **create a blended feed of the two blogs** you'd like to feature on their LinkedIn page, then use the URL of the blended feed in LinkedIn.

There are several [sites that will mix two feeds into one](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/10-tools-to-combine-mix-blend-multiple-rss-feeds/) for you, but [ChimpFeedr](http://www.chimpfeedr.com/) and [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) are among the most dependable.